# How do I reconnect a project directory to github when I've made untracked changes?

Tags: git, github

I have a project directory that has been version controlled with `git` and pushed to Github. It is also backed up to OneDrive. My computer died and I downloaded my project from OneDrive and kept working on it, but did not initialize a `git` repository. Now I want to reconnect the local project directory to the remote repository without overwriting my local changes. i.e., I want to initialize a local repository, commit my new changes, and have my local changes take precedent over the Github versions, but I want to keep the version history from before my computer died.

What's the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+directory

Comment: @phd that post worked for me. Thanks! I didn't know what were the best search terms.

Answer (score -1):

- Clone your repository into a new directory
- Copy/Paste your WorkInProgress directory into the cloned directory
- Git will detect the difference, and show you your changes